# Función con figuras

Tags: c++

Buenas tardes, estoy intentando realizar un programa en Dev C++, en el que la función reciba como argumento el nombre de alguna figura (pino, estrella o corona e imprima en pantalla el dibujo que mencionen; llevo esto:

```
PINO, ESTRELLA, CORONA])
{

    switch(figura)
    {
        case PINO;
            {   
                cout<<"\n"<<endl;
                cout<<"            #                " <<endl;
                cout<<"           # #               " <<endl;
                cout<<"          #   #              " <<endl;
                cout<<"         #     #             " <<endl;
                cout<<"        #       #            " <<endl;
                cout<<"       #         #           " <<endl;
                cout<<"      #           #          " <<endl;
                cout<<"     #             #         " <<endl;
                cout<<"    #               #        " <<endl;
                cout<<"   ###################       " <<endl;
                cout<<"           ###               " <<endl;
                cout<<"           ###               " <<endl;
                cout<<"           ###               " <<endl;

                break;
            }
        case ESTRELLA;
            {   
                cout<<"\n"<<endl;
                cout<<"                        #             " <<endl;
                cout<<"                       ###            " <<endl;
                cout<<"                      #####           " <<endl;
                cout<<"                     #######          " <<endl;
                cout<<"             #######################  " <<endl;
                cout<<"                #################     " <<endl;
                cout<<"                  #############       " <<endl;
                cout<<"                   ###########        " <<endl;
                cout<<"                    #########         " <<endl;
                cout<<"                   ###########        " <<endl;
                cout<<"                  #####   #####       " <<endl;
                cout<<"                 ###         ###      " <<endl;
                cout<<"                #               #     " <<endl;
                break;
            }
        case CORONA;
            {   
                cout<<"\n"<<endl;
                cout<<"   #       #       #       #       #        #    " <<endl;
                cout<<"    ##    ###     ###     ###     ###     ##     " <<endl;
                cout<<"     ### #####   #####   #####   #####  ###      " <<endl;
                cout<<"      ####################################       " <<endl;
                cout<<"      ####################################       " <<endl;               
                break;

            }
                default;
                    cout<<"\n"<<endl;
                    cout<<"Su selección no corresponde a ninguna figura" <<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char figura;
    cout<<" Escribe el nombre de la figura "<<endl;
    cout<<"\n";
    system("cls");

    dibujar(figura);
}
```

pero no identifico cual es el error. Si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Una declaración `SWITCH` solo se puede usar para valores integrales, no para valores del tipo definido por el usuario. E incluso si pudiera, tu operación de entrada tampoco funciona.

Debes utilizar `string` para almacenar valores que tengan más de un caracter ya que el conjunto de caracteres lo que conforma es una cadena.

Es posible que desees realizar esto:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

enum opcion {pino, estrella, corona};
map<string, opcion> opciones;

void iniciarOpciones()
{
    opciones["pino"]   = pino;
    opciones["estrella"] = estrella;
    opciones["corona"]   = corona;
}

void dibujar(string figura)
{
    switch( opciones[figura] )
    {
    case pino:
        cout << "\n" << endl;
                cout << "            #                " <<endl;
                cout << "           # #               " <<endl;
                cout << "          #   #              " <<endl;
                cout << "         #     #             " <<endl;
                cout << "        #       #            " <<endl;
                cout << "       #         #           " <<endl;
                cout << "      #           #          " <<endl;
                cout << "     #             #         " <<endl;
                cout << "    #               #        " <<endl;
                cout << "   ###################       " <<endl;
                cout << "           ###               " <<endl;
                cout << "           ###               " <<endl;
                cout << "           ###               " <<endl;
                break;
    case estrella:
        cout<<"\n"<<endl;
                cout<<"                        #             " <<endl;
                cout<<"                       ###            " <<endl;
                cout<<"                      #####           " <<endl;
                cout<<"                     #######          " <<endl;
                cout<<"             #######################  " <<endl;
                cout<<"                #################     " <<endl;
                cout<<"                  #############       " <<endl;
                cout<<"                   ###########        " <<endl;
                cout<<"                    #########         " <<endl;
                cout<<"                   ###########        " <<endl;
                cout<<"                  #####   #####       " <<endl;
                cout<<"                 ###         ###      " <<endl;
                cout<<"                #               #     " <<endl;
                break;
    case corona:
                cout<<"\n"<<endl;
                cout<<"   #       #       #       #       #        #    " <<endl;
                cout<<"    ##    ###     ###     ###     ###     ##     " <<endl;
                cout<<"     ### #####   #####   #####   #####  ###      " <<endl;
                cout<<"      ####################################       " <<endl;
                cout<<"      ####################################       " <<endl;
                break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    iniciarOpciones();
    string figura;
    cout<<" Escribe el nombre de la figura "<<endl;
    cin >> figura;
    cout<<"\n";
    system("cls");
    dibujar(figura);
}
```

Comment: La entrada al `switch` suele ser una variable... es decir, un valor definido por el usuario... lo que no admite esta estructura son tipos no nativos... como clases, cadenas de caracteres... arrays...

Comment: Así,  por ejemplo, se podrían usar los valores de un enumerado sin problemas... pero antes habría que convertir la cadena de texto en un enumerado... que es lo que le estaba fallando en el código de la pregunta

Comment: Si, tiene que convertir el STRING a INT

Comment: Pues esa es la parte que le falta a tu respuesta para adaptarse al código de la pregunta.

Comment: Ok. Lo modifico!

Comment: La respuesta ha sido modificada, espero sea de ayuda..

Answer (score -1):

Los elementos del switch no terminan con un `;`, sino que terminan con un `:`

```
void dibujar(string figura) {
  switch(figura) {
    case "Pino":
      //
      break;
    case "Corona":
      //
      break;
    case "Estrella":
      //
      break;
    default:
      //
      break;
  }
}
```

Debes usar una `string` para pedir el nombre de la figura, esto para que puedas almacenar más de un caracter.

```
int main(){
  cout << "Que figura: ";
  string f;
  cin >> f;
  dibujar(f);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: La condición del switch debe ser un tipo entero o enumeración.

Comment: Acostumbra a verificar que la solución que propones compila y funciona